# Environment variable for Apple Shake 4.1

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, high-sierra, environment-variables

Where is Shake's environment variable located in macOS allowing to launch Shake.app via Terminal session in High Sierra?

There's no Shake's variables in `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're able to access the `shake` command line tool because it's in a directory that's listed in the `PATH` environment variable in your environment.

If you want to know the precise location of the `shake` executable you can type:

```
which shake
```

Which will list the first place it finds the `shake` executable when it searches all the directories in the `PATH` environment variable.

If you want to see all the places `shake` exists you can type:

```
which -a shake
```

And that will list all of the places where a command called `shake` can be found. I don't have `shake` on my machine, but here's an example using `bash`. The first occurence of the `bash` executable for me:

```
IanCsiMac:~
> which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

And all the places I can find a `bash` executable in my `PATH`:

```
IanCsiMac:~
> which -a bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
/bin/bash
```

And my `PATH` variable looks like this:

```
IanCsiMac:~
> perl -e 'print join("\n", split(/:/,$ENV{"PATH"}))'
/Users/ian/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/bin
/Users/ian/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bin
/Users/ian/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/Users/ian/google-cloud-sdk/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/Users/ian/bin
/opt/nginx/sbin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/Users/ian/Development/go/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash command **`which shake`** gives me the following result:

```
/usr/bin/shake
```

And the content of the **`shake`** file in **`/usr/bin/`** contains a script like this:

```
# set env var, NR_SHAKE_LOCATION if not set

if ${?NR_SHAKE_LOCATION} == 0 then
    pushd `dirname $0` >& /dev/null
    setenv NR_SHAKE_LOCATION /Applications/Shake
    popd >& /dev/null
endif

# launch shake

exec ${NR_SHAKE_LOCATION}/shake.app/Contents/MacOS/shake $argv:q
```